# Create Trigger For Update another row automatically on same table using postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers, user-defined-functions

I want to create a trigger that can update another row on the same table on PostgreSQL.

if i run the query like these:

```
UPDATE tokens
SET amount = (SELECT amount FROM tokens WHERE id = 1)
where id = 2
```

these result that i expected.

description:

i want to set field `amount` on a row with `id:2`, where the `amount` value is from query result on a subquery, so the amount value on `id:2` is same with `id:1`

Hopefully, with this created trigger, i can do update `amount` value on `id=1` so the `amount` value on `id:2` is same with `id:1`

Before update result:

```
id | amount|
1  | 200   |
2  | 200   |
```

When i update the `amount` value on `id:1` to 100 on, so the `amount` value on `id:2` become 100

After update result:

```
id | amount|
1  | 100   | 
2  | 100   |
```

Update for my temporary solution:
i just create the UDF like these

```
CREATE FUNCTION update_amount(id_ops integer, id_mir integer) returns boolean LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
 UPDATE tokens SET amount = (SELECT amount FROM tokens WHERE id = id_ops) WHERE id = id_mir;
 RETURN 1;
END;
$$;
```

description:

1. id_ops: id where the amount i always update
2. id_mir: id where the amount automatically update after i update the amount with id_ops

Example of using my written UDF to resolve my problem:

1. I update the amount of id: 1 to 2000. The amount of id: 2 not updated to 2000
2. When i run query select update_amount(1,2);
3. The amount of id: 2 will same with amount on id: 1

I Need a trigger on PostgreSQL to automate or replace the function of UDF that i wrote

Comment: What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i have a difficulty to convert my UDF i wrote to trigger, so i can replace my temporary solution. Regards

Comment: Is the row you want to update the one you just inserted or a different one?

Comment: Hi the row that I always update is id 1, when I update the amount value on id 1, the amount value on id 2 mirror from updated amount value id 1

Comment: Is the general condition *always* the case that you want id N+1 when update id N is updated? What would happen for "update tokens set amount = 10 where id = 3;"? or even "update tokens set amount = 50 where id = 2;"?

Comment: Hi, actually right now I only updated only on id:1, when I use my written UDF, I set it to mirror on id:2. Maybe for another case if I insert data for for id 3 and id 4. I update the id 3, might be id 2 I can set mirror from id 3, or for usual from id 1. So the big question how to convert my written UDF to trigger, so I can automate the process. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do it not really that difficult, I'll show you. But first: This is a very very **bad** idea. In fact bad enough that some databases, most notable Oracle, throw an exception if try it. Unfortunately Postgres allows it.  You essentially create a recursive update as you are updating the table that initiated the trigger. This update in turn initiates the trigger. Without logic to stop this recursion you could update every row in the table.  
 
I assume this is an extract for a much larger requirement, or perhaps you just want to know how to create a trigger. So we begin:

```
-- setup
drop table if exists tokens;
create table tokens( id integer, amount numeric(6,2));
-- create initial test data
insert into tokens(id, amount)
  values (1,100), (2,150.69), (3,95.50), (4,75), (5,16.40);
```

Now the heart Postgres trigger: the [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html), and the trigger. Note the function must be defined prior to the trigger which calls it.

```
-- create a trigger function: That is a function returning trigger.
create or replace function tokens_bur_func()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    if new.id = 1
    then
        update tokens
           set amount = new.amount
         where id = 2;
    end if;
    return new;
end ;
$$;

-- create the trigger
create trigger tokens_bur
    before update of amount 
    on tokens
    for each row execute procedure tokens_bur_func();

--- test 
select *
  from tokens
 order by id; 

-- do an initial update
update tokens
   set amount = 200
 where id = 1;
-- Query returned successfully: one row affected, 31 msec execution time. 
-- 1 row? Yes:  DML count does not see change made from within trigger.
-- but
select *
  from tokens
 order by id;
```

Hard coding ids in a trigger however is not very functional after all "update ... where id in (1,2)" would be much easier, and safer as it does not require the recursion stop logic. So a slightly more generic trigger function is:

```
-- More general but still vastly limited:
-- trigger that mirrors subsequent row whenever an odd id is updated.
create or replace function tokens_bur_func()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    if mod(new.id, 2)=1
    then 
        update tokens
           set amount = new.amount
         where id = new.id+1;
    end if;
    return new;
end ;
$$; 

-- test
update tokens
   set amount = 900
 where id = 3; 

update tokens
   set amount = 18.95
 where id in (2,5);

select *
  from tokens
 order by id;
```

No matter how you proceed you required prior knowledge of update specifics. For example you said "might be id 2 I can set mirror from id 3" to do so you would need to alter the database in some manner either changing the trigger function or the trigger to pass parameters. (Triggers can pass parameters but they are static, supplied at create trigger time).  
Finally make sure you got your recursion stop logic down cold. Because if not:

```
-- The Danger: What happens WITHOUT the 'stopper condition'
-- Using an almost direct conversion of your UDT
-- using new_id as  
create or replace function tokens_bur_func()
returns trigger
language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
    update tokens
       set amount = new.amount
     where id = new.id+1;
    return new;
end ;
$$;  

-- test
update tokens
   set amount = 137.92
 where id = 1; 
-- Query returned successfully: one row affected, 31 msec execution time. 
-- but 
select *
  from tokens
 order by id;
```